# Azure Analysis Services Out of Memory

Tags: azure, ssas, ssas-tabular

We have our data stored in azure analysis services B1 Tier. Power bi report deployed in a premium workspace is
consuming the Model using live query. We are facing issue with AAS that the model is not releasing the memory
once the report is consumed by the users. Memory is released only after the service is restarted. Is this because of the B1 tier that we use? Is there any better way to
handle the caching ? Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Analysis Services releases memory as required, based on the demands placed on the model.  It does not do this as soon as a report is rendered as this is not how it is designed to work and would negatively impact performance.

You see the memory utilisation drop after restarting because the cached data generated by the Vertipaq engine is flushed, though this will be rebuilt as soon as you start querying the model again.

It sounds like you have some rather intensive dashboard measures or too much data for the Basic tier, which is [a general-purpose tier and recommended for production solutions with *small Tabular models, limited user concurrency and simple data refresh requirements*](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/analysis-services/).

Your solution here is to do some combination of:

1. Upgrade your AAS instance
2. Reduce the amount of data in your model
3. Reduce the number of users
4. Reduce the complexity of your reports
5. Optimise your DAX measures